# How to use ArrayList<String> value for displaying in AchartEngine in android?

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to display ArrayList value in graph(AchartEngine). I got ArrayList values from JSON webservice.How to display graph data using arraylist string value? Is any method for converting whole arraylist values?

```
JSONObject jObject = JSONParser.getJsonFromURL(temp_url);
String flag = jObject.getString("Flag");
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("TempTransList");
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject job = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String BuildingId = job.getString("BuildingId");
    String BuildingSegmentId = job.getString("BuildingSegmentId");
    ..String Customer_ID = job.getString("Customer_ID");
    String DateTime = job.getString("DateTime");
    //String InnerLocationId = job.getString("InnerLocationId");
    String Temp_Date = job.getString("TempDate");
    String Temp_Time = job.getString("TempTime");
    String Temperature = job.getString("Temperature");

    temp_details.add(Temperature);
    date_time.add(DateTime);
    temp_date.add(Temp_Date);
    temp_time.add(Temp_Time);
```

chart initialization code here:

```
private void initializeChartNew() {   
    // Creating an XYSeries for Income
    XYSeries fromTemp = new XYSeries("From Temperature");
    // Creating an XYSeries for Expense
    XYSeries toTemp = new XYSeries("To Temperature");
    arrayX = new double[temp_time.size()];
    from_date = new double[date_time.size()];
    to_date = new double[temp_date.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < temp_time.size(); i++) {
        fromTemp.add(arrayX[i], from_date[i]);
        toTemp.add(arrayX[i], to_date[i]);

        //System.out.println("value of arrayX "+arrayX);
        //System.out.println("value of from_date "+from_date);
        //System.out.println("value of to_date "+to_date);
    }

    System.out.println("value of temp_time "+temp_time.size());
    System.out.println("value of arrayX "+arrayX);
    System.out.println("value of from_date "+from_date);
    System.out.println("value of to_date "+to_date);

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    // Adding Income Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(fromTemp);
    // Adding Expense Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(toTemp);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer from_tempRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    from_tempRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    from_tempRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    from_tempRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    from_tempRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    from_tempRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer to_tempRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    to_tempRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    to_tempRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    to_tempRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    to_tempRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    to_tempRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(16);
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(12);
    multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(12);
    multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Temperature Detail");
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Time");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Temperature");
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < temp_details.size(); i++) {
        multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, temp_details.get(i));
        System.out.println("value of temp_details name " + temp_details.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println("value of temp_details " + temp_details.size());
    // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to
    // multipleRenderer
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(from_tempRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(to_tempRenderer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this one


for (int i = 0; i <= mList.size(); i++) {
multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mList.get(i));
}
```